# Converting an Oracle Stored Procedure to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I'm facing an Oracle to PostgreSQL migration: I managed to convert tables and views however I'm a bit stuck with Stored Procedures.

I've started with this one, which looks like this in Oracle:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure
  update_role_func_def(function_id varchar2)
as
  cursor role_list_cursor is
   select r.id from amm_role r
    for update of r.id
   ;
begin
  for role_record in role_list_cursor
   loop
     insert into AMM_ROLE_FUNC_DEF (RID, FID, GRANT_FUNCT) values (role_record.id,    function_id, 'N');
  end loop;

  commit;
end update_role_func_def;
```

looking at the docs I managed to create this equivalent:

```
CREATE FUNCTION 
  update_role_func_def(function_id varchar)
  returns void 
as
$$
DECLARE
  cursor role_list_cursor is
    select r.id from amm_role r  for update of r.id  ;
begin
  for role_record in role_list_cursor
  loop
    insert into AMM_ROLE_FUNC_DEF (RID, FID, GRANT_FUNCT) values (role_record.id, function_id, 'N');
  end loop;

  commit;
end ;
$$
```

However entering this procedure in the PgAdmin results in a "Syntax Error, unexpected CREATE, expecting ';'

I feel a bit lost: is there any Postgres developer that can give me a clue if the procedure is syntactically correct ?

Comment: You can't use `commit` inside a function in Postgres. And you don't need the cursor at all (neither in Oracle nor in Postgres), this can be done with a single `INSERT ... SELECT statement`. And why do you use `for update` if you are not updating `amm_role` at all?

Comment: Do it with `sql` only (no `declare`, `begin`, `end`) as suggested by @a_horse unless there is more in the function that needs plpgsql. Declare the used language `language sql` or `language plpgsql`

Comment: Found this tool (online and offline) while searching for the same thing : http://www.sqlines.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless there is more to this than you are telling us, the following should work:

```
create or replace function update_role_func_def(function_id varchar)
  returns void 
as
$$
  insert into AMM_ROLE_FUNC_DEF (RID, FID, GRANT_FUNCT) 
  select r.id, function_id, 'N'
  from amm_role r;
$$
language sql;
```

Here is an SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/aed49/1

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I really needed an initial bootstrap :-)